# ¿Por qué un método implementado siempre retorna 0?

Tags: java, poo, lista, clase, arraylist

Tengo una pregunta sobre el siguiente código: ¿Por qué el método `duracionTotal()` siempre retorna `0`, es decir, no devuelve lo que tenia que devolver (la duración total de un CD)?

**Ejercicio:** 1. Se quiere almacenar la información sobre 100 CDs de música. Por cada CD se guarda el título, su autor y una lista con las canciones que contiene. Por cada canción guardamos su título y su duración en segundos. a) Definir la estructura de datos más adecuada para almacenar la información. b) Implementar un método que, dado un título de CD, devuelva su duración total. c) Implementar un método que, dado un título de canción, devuelva el título y autor del CD en que se encuentra.

```
class CD {

private String titulo, autor;
List<Cancion> listaCans = new ArrayList<Cancion>();

CD(String titulo, String autor, List listaCans) {
    this.autor = autor;
    this.listaCans = listaCans;
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

CD() {
}

String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

void setTitulo() {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

double duracionTotalCD(String titulo, List listaCDs, List listaCanss) {
    double duracionT = 0;

    boolean e;

    CD c = new CD();

    Iterator it = listaCans.iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        c = (CD) listaCDs.get(i);

        String t = c.getTitulo();

        if (0 == t.compareTo(titulo)) {

            while (it.hasNext()) {

                duracionT = +(double)
            (c.listaCans.get(i).getDuracion());
            }
        }


    }
    return duracionT;
}
}

class Cancion {

private String titulo;
private double duracion;

Cancion() {
}

Cancion(String titulo, double duracion) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.duracion = duracion;
}

double getDuracion() {
    return duracion;

}
}

public class EjercicioClase1sep {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List listaCanss = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<CD> listaCDs = new ArrayList<>();
    CD x = new CD();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Nombre CD:");
        leer.nextLine();
        String nomCD = leer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Autor CD:");
        String aut = leer.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            System.out.println("Nombre cancion:");
            leer.nextLine();
            String nomCan = leer.nextLine();

            System.out.println("duracion cancion:");
            double dur = leer.nextInt();
            listaCanss.add(new Cancion(nomCan, dur));
        }

        listaCDs.add(new CD(nomCD, aut, listaCanss));
    }
    double w = x.duracionTotalCD("Circus", listaCDs, listaCanss);
    System.out.println("La duracion total del CD es: " + w);}}
```

Comment: Dos cosas, veo que en tu metodo "duracionTotalCD" tienes un if que condiciona para sumar, realmente entra en dicho if!? y segundo, te funciona esta expresión!? "duracionT = +(double)(c.listaCans.get(i).getDuracion());" es decir "= +" no te da error!?

Comment: @Rostan no, no me marca error aqui `duracionT = +(double)(c.listaCans.get(i).getDuracion());`.

Comment: @Rostan se supone que tiene que entrar (no se porque no lo hace..), ya le mande datos en el main:    `double w = x.duracionTotalCD("Circus", listaCDs, listaCanss);` y cuando ejecute el programa le puse "Circus" en el nombre del disco, para que coincidiera

Comment: Entonces deberías editar tu pregunta, ya que el método se esta cumpliendo, tu problema real está en la formulación del IF, ya que nunca se cumple segun como tu lo deseas. Lo que asumo que quieres hacer es comparar el STRING que ingresa con el titulo del CD, al ser 2 cadenas de texto, cambia el método ".comparteTo" por ".equals" y prueba.

Comment: Otra cosa que queria preguntarte, que quieres decir con ese if!? es que no entiendo 0 == t.compareTo(titulo).

Comment: t.compareTo(titulo) devuelve 0 si t==titulo, devuelve 1 o -1 si son distintos, o algo asi..la cosa  es que si devuelve 0 entonces son iguales. @Rostan

Comment: Ya lo cambie por `.equals`, `if(true == t.equals(titulo))` pero aun asi sigue dando `0` :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64981/discussion-between-rostan-and-michelle).

Answer (score 1):

Estudiando tu programa en profundidad, lo he codificado entero y, con todos mis respetos, no hay por donde cogerlo. He aquí una serie de fallos a nivel lógico:

> - No puedes intentar imprimir la duración del CD si solicitas el nombre del CD dos veces, ya que tendrías 2CDs.
> - Tu método `duracionTotalCD(Titulo, ListaCDs, ListaCanns)` me resulta muy confuso. Compruebas si el titulo `Circus` está en alguno de los CDs y de ser así, lo sumas a `duracion` para devolver la duración del CD.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo reciclado de tu código de lo que intentas hacer. No es la mejor decisión de codificación ya que el código está muy mezclado, pero es completamente funcional y creo que te pueda servir para entender mejor lo que quieres hacer.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

class CD {

private String titulo, autor;
List<Cancion> listaCans = new ArrayList<Cancion>();

CD(String titulo, String autor, List listaCans) {
    this.autor = autor;
    this.listaCans = listaCans;
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

CD() {
}

List getCanciones(){
    return listaCans;
}

String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

void setTitulo() {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

double duracionTotalCD( List<CD> listaCDs) {
    double duracionT = 0.0;
        for(CD cd : listaCDs){
            List<Cancion> listaCanciones = cd.getCanciones();
            for(Cancion cancion : listaCanciones){
                duracionT += cancion.getDuracion();
            }
        }
    return duracionT;
}
}

class Cancion {

private String titulo;
private double duracion;

Cancion() {
}

Cancion(String titulo, double duracion) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.duracion = duracion;
}

double getDuracion() {
    return duracion;

}
}

public class EjercicioClase1sep {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List listaCanss = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<CD> listaCDs = new ArrayList<>();
    CD x = new CD();

    // Pide los datos del CD y del autor 1 sola vez
    System.out.println("Nombre CD:");
    String nomCD = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Autor CD:");
    String aut = leer.nextLine();

    //  Pide el nombre de la cancion y su duracion 2 veces 
    //  (se considera que es un disco con dos canciones)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        System.out.println("Nombre cancion:");
        String nomCan = leer.nextLine();

        System.out.println("duracion cancion:");
        double dur = leer.nextInt(); // Pide un entero y lo almacena en un double

        leer.nextLine(); // Limpia el buffer de la sentencia anterior (eliminando el intro)
        listaCanss.add(new Cancion(nomCan, dur));
    }

    listaCDs.add(new CD(nomCD, aut, listaCanss));

    double w = x.duracionTotalCD(listaCDs);
    System.out.println("La duracion total del CD es: " + w);
}
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: hmm el método `double duracionTotalCD( List<CD> listaCDs)` debe recibir  también como parametro un `String TituloDelCD`, y luego ver si `TituloDelCD` coincide con algun titulo de listaCDs

Comment: Pero entonces en la introducción de datos, ¿cuántos CDs introduces al iniciar el programa?

Comment: 2 CDs, y por tanto 4 canciones, 2 en cada CD